# Acumatica validation error when using PXSelect

Tags: c#, acumatica

Every time I try to select a specific data record based on a column criteria Acumatica throws an error saying that the type name does not exist, when in the table it absolutely does.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
If I remove the "where" part of the statement, it validates fine; however that is not what I need to do.

Here is the error message
\App_RuntimeCode\CRActivityMaint.cs(34): error CS0426: The type name 'NoteID' does not exist in the type 'Contact'

Here is the code

````
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using PX.CS;
using PX.Data.EP;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.Common.GraphExtensions.Abstract;
using System.Web.Compilation;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Data.BQL.Fluent;
using PX.Data.BQL;

namespace PX.Objects.EP
{
  public class CRActivityMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CRActivityMaint>
  {
  
    protected void CRActivity_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
      {
        var task = (CR.CRActivity)e.Row;
        var taskExt = task.GetExtension<CR.CRActivityExt>();

        if (taskExt != null)
          {

            Contact contactInfo = PXSelect<Contact, Where<Contact.NoteID, Equal<Required<Contact.NoteID>>>>.Select(this.Base, 100862);                      

          }
      }
       
    #region Event Handlers

    #endregion
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoteID is a GUID stored as an uniqueidentifier in SQL (Ex '5D0C3B2C-D87F-E411-BECA-00B56D0561C2').  I suggest you try using a GUID parameter.

Comment: Patrick, I actually had changed that value when I posted this code.  I actually AM using a GUID value at the end of that statement.  The original statement should have read like below and it is not working.  My apologies for the confusion.

Contact contactInfo = PXSelect<Contact, Where<Contact.NoteID, Equal<Required<Contact.NoteID>>>>.Select(this.Base, "E2156824-6AD7-EA11-8176-D002F6E7F394");

Comment: Looking through the source I see a lot of examples of using a different type in the Required bracket. I would suggest you try something like Where<Contact.NoteID, Equal<Required<CRActivity.CreatedByID>>>>.Select(this.Base,'...

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to respond.  That is not working either.  using CRActivity.RefNoteID.  Which in SQL works perfectly.  I am still seeing the errors below.  In SQL the following works perfectly SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE NoteID = CRActivity.RefNoteID AND NoteID = 'E2156824-6AD7-EA11-8176-D002F6E7F394' 
  This is an Acumatica C# problem. 
  \App_RuntimeCode\CRActivityMaint.cs(37): error CS0426: The type name 'NoteID' does not exist in the type 'Contact'
\App_RuntimeCode\CRActivityMaint.cs(37): error CS0426: The type name 'RefNoteID' does not exist in the type 'CRActivity'

Comment: Ok, you'll hate this one.  NoteID should be noteID.

Comment: LOL....That Works!  I do not hate that at all!  I am very glad it was something that simple, and I was simply not seeing it.  Thank you!  BTW, RefNoteID also needed to be refNoteID.  It all works now.  Thank you again for being my additional pair of eyes.